# Footer with sidenav

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to create a footer with anuglar material sidenav that will appear under all of the navbar and its content, snapped to the bottom. The result I am getting is that navbar is not being stretched all the way to the footer if there is not enough content.
 [Here is the link to example](https://angular-material-footer-nr437r.stackblitz.io/) of what I get. [This is the editor link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-footer-nr437r)

Answer (score 0):

```
.mat-drawer-container {
    position: inherit;
    z-index: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

```
.mat-drawer-container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%!important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @loan Beilic. This is a good direction, but the z-index:-1; actually makes all the links and button on toolbar not clickable.